# (C++) For loop - why does it do this?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm a student of C++, and I'm having some trouble understanding why this for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Displays output as such: 0000011111222223333344444

I understand that the outer loop is executed after the inner loop is done. But, were that the case, wouldn't the output look like 0123401234012340123401234? If the inner loop has to complete first, why doesn't it have that pattern?

Comment: Because you're outputting `i`, not `j`

Comment: This isn't the code that produced that output.

Comment: This question is a great example of why using both i and j as loop iterators is usually a poor choice. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I understand that the outer loop is executed after the inner loop is done. But, were that the case, wouldn't the output look like 0123401234012340123401234? If the inner loop has to complete first, why doesn't it have that pattern?*

No, the outer for() is executed normally. But for each loop of the outer for(), it executes the entire inner for().

```
Outer for(), loop 1:
  i = 0;
  Inner for(), loop 1-5:
  Print "i" (which is 0) five times. ("00000")

Outer for(), loop 2:
  i = 1;
  Inner for(), loop 1-5:
  Print "i" (which is 1) five times. ("11111")

Outer for(), loop 3: etc...
```

Comment: Thank you - very elaborate and useful.

Answer (score 3):

Because you aren't printing `j`, the variable of the inner loop, but `i`, the variable from the outer loop. Otherwise, the output would be just as you predicted. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are printing `i` in the inner loop. If you were printing `j` then it would be `0123401234012340123401234`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the variable displayed is `i` and not `j`, `i` is displayed 5 times in the inner loop and then its value is changed in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do what everyone else has said, if you need the code, you change one letter:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
        cout << j << endl;
    }
}
```

I also put the open braces on the same line as the for statement, it makes absolutely no difference in terms of running, but I think it looks cleaner, and it makes your code look shorter.

Comment: The brackets are a matter of preference - sure it makes your code "look shorter" (but it's the same exact number of characters, so it's not really shorter), but at the same time it makes missing brackets harder to visually detect. There are pros and cons to almost every coding style.

Comment: It is, which is why I said it makes no difference. And there technically is one more character (enter), which can take a tiny bit longer to post, but it's how I like to look at my code, because it's especially helpful for else if statements, when you can easily see what the else if is attatched to.

Comment: I also prefer the opening brace at the end of the line that begins a block. However, the choice often comes down to the style adopted by an organization. (And if that organization consists of just one individual -- that would be *you*.)

Comment: @newbie: I was counting the enter. You replaced the newline with a space between the for() and the opening bracket. =P

Comment: Well aren't you smart.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the desired output if you simply change:

```
cout << i << endl;
```

...to

```
cout << j << endl;
```

Also, regarding style, in your `for` loops consider changing `i++` and `j++` to `++i` and `++j`. For the reason why, from the C++ FAQ see [**13.15** Which is more efficient: i++ or ++i?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/increment-pre-post-speed.html) :

**Excerpt:**

> Old line C programmers are used to writing `i++` instead of `++i`. E.g.,
>   they'll say, `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)` .... Since this uses `i++` as a
>   statement, not as a part of a larger expression, then you might want
>   to use `++i` instead. For symmetry, I personally advocate that style
>   even when it doesn't improve speed,...

Comment: I did not think of this. Though I wasn't using the variables in a larger expression which I wanted to be calculated first - and then have the variable incremented - I kind of just defaulted to i++ anyway. Nice tip for a learner, I will use ++i now. Cheers.

Comment: As a long time programmer, I was surprised myself when I came across this tip. Proof that in this business one never stops learning. Also, generally speaking, the C++ FAQ to which I refer is an outstanding resource. It's a great starting point when you are seeking to understand a new concept. Also, as someone new to StackOverflow, don't be afraid to upvote answers that you find helpful. And, of course, choose one answer to accept if you feel it best answers your question. (This may not necessarily be my answer in this particular case.)

Comment: I've bookmarked the FAQ and now have it a click away so I'll be able to access it whenever I need to do so. I was trying to upvote some answers, but I apparently need at least 15 reputation before I can upvote or downvote. I believe I'll have accumulated enough soon, as I think I'll be fairly active here from thus on; this site is a great resource because of such helpful members as you.

Comment: Hmmm, its been a while, but I thought a new SO member could begin voting right away. That said, definitely also bookmark [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) and from that FAQ check out [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Comment: And also [When should I vote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote)